# I need help fixing my batch file in execution to powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to call these powershell scripts in a batch file, as follows:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  d:\1.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  d:\2.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  d:\3.ps1
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  d:\4.ps1
```

I run that batch file and is giving me the following error for `2.ps1`,`3.ps1` and`4.ps1`

> the argument d:\2.ps1 for the parameter -file doesnt exist. Provide the path of access to the file d:\2.ps1 (2.3.4) existent as argument for the parameter -file"

The files are in the drives where i am calling them, 3 and 4 fails to execute because are connected to script `2.ps1`.

I dont know what is the problem in calling `2.ps1`, after `1.ps1` because it is the same commnd, if I execute the files manually, they run just fine.

Comment: basically what im going is in the batch file calling a net use, in 1) deleting "ok" and "microsoft bla bla" in 2) im adding in the end of each line /persistent yes in 3) im deleting every empty space and every empty line in 4) im adding at the begging of each line net use and making an "mapped drives.bat"

as and example of end of this equation is: net use  x: \\server\drive /persistent yes . Name of bat mapped drives.bat

Comment: Are the scripts all signed? Or in other words, why are you specifying RemoteSigned as the execution policy? Not sure this has anything to do with your issue, as the error message implies powershell can't open the 2.ps1 file. Just asking.

Comment: is giving me the same error even if i take out remote signed i dont know why..

Comment: What happens when you wrap all your paths in double quotes? for instance. `-File "D:\2.ps1"`

Comment: What are the real names and paths of your powershell scripts? because, let's be honest, no sane minded person creates scripts with single digit names in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like this:

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "d:\1.ps1"
```